# Inserting Array into multiple sql fields php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

This should be really easy but I am struggling.

Here is my current code

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
$friend_id = $friend['id'];
}
$connections = "INSERT INTO connections (user_id, friend_id) VALUES ('$id', '$friend_id')";
```

$friend_id = $friend['id']; should be a list of 1000 id's. I want row created in a table for each $friend_id using the same $id

Thanks!

Comment: Umm not necessarily. All I want to do is have 1000 rows created for 1000 of my friends ids

Comment: You say $friend_id should be a list of 1000 ids - do I interpret that correctly? How is that delimited? Is it a delimited string, or is $friend_id an array?

Comment: $friend_id is an array. And yes it should be a list of 1000 ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
$friend_id = $friend['id'];
$connections = "INSERT INTO connections (user_id, friend_id) VALUES ('$id', '$friend_id')";
mysql_query($connections);
}
```

Like that? You must execute the query once for each row.

Comment: This looks right but for some reason it is only create one row. I know $friend['id'] would echo 1000 id's but when I try to execute the query it only does one of them.

Comment: First make sure that the query is being executed inside the foreach loop. Also verify that you actually have 1000 friends in the $friends['data'] array. You can do that by using the `print_r($friends['data']);`

Comment: Yeah I tested that and am getting a list of 1000 ids.

Comment: Could be a problem with your database. What is the structure of the connections table?

Comment: Just two columns. Both int(100).

Comment: It could come down to many things... which row is appearing in your table? The first or last one in the list of IDs?

Comment: The first id in the list is appearing in the database.

Comment: With what @gummy24 wrote that's what I would expect - if $friend_id is an array you'll just get a single row with the one user_id and a list of the friend_ids.  If you want to verify, execute  print_r($connections); .

Comment: The only problem is that it is stopping after the first friend id. There isn't 1000 id's in the friend_id field. Just one.

Comment: I misunderstood when you said $friend_id was an array, above.

Comment: It's like it performs the first foreach and then just stops.

Comment: When I print_r($friend_list) it shows 703145,706281,1005698,1224899,1916404,2330100,...etc... and no commas breaking them up I just added those so you could tell where the first id stopped and the 2nd one began.

Comment: Check if its the foreach loop that is breaking or the query. 
1. echo 'something' in the loop. See if it echos 1000 times.
2. echo the query out. see if in each loop its different
3. echo mysql_error() after the execution of the query to see if there the database is throwing anything at you

I'm sorry but that's all I can think of.

Comment: What is this $friend_list of which you speak? I don't see that in any of the code posted yet.

Comment: One aspect of the schema that might be important is the key structure. If $user_id is the primary key then you'll get a duplicate key error in MySQL and just one row.

Comment: cori's answer is probably what you are looking at. You didn't mention anything about a primary key so i assumed there were none.

Comment: That was it! I moved the primary key to the friend_id.

Comment: I don't think that's what you should be doing... what if you decide to enter other users with their own friends in that table and there are duplicate of the friend_id? You will get the same problem. Add a connection_id column, set it to auto_increment and make it the primary key.

Comment: I would suggest using a compound key of user_id, friend_id in this case.  Otherwise if you run this against another user who has overlapping friends you'll get the same error there. Actually, if it were me I would probably add a key field and set it to auto-increment so you have a standalone key that's not related to either data field, but it all depends on how you're using the data.

Comment: You guys are the best. I am going to add another column that will auto inc. Thanks!